# Akka for distributed pub sub with wild card topics

Tags: java, scala, akka, publish-subscribe

I am interested in understanding the best practices or examples around distributed pub-sub in akka for wild card topics or filters.

For example, I plan to have to a setup where some actors subscribe to wild card topics like A/B/* or A/*/C etc. Additionally, there are publishing actors which publishing actors, which publish on full named topic like A/B/F or A/B/C etc. The example in http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.2.0/contrib/distributed-pub-sub.html works only for subscriptions for full named topics.

Any documentation or working examples would be really helpful. Solutions with brokers in between would also work.

Comment: Same problem here, have you found any solution for the wildcarded topics?